# Read/write data then separate data

Tags: c++

I am a newbie in C++. I am doing a C++ sign up form where I keep all the user datas in a text file named user.txt with formats like

```
name|password|address|postal|phone
```

Each user record will occupy one line.

So my first question how can I do this nicely in C++

As for the reading part, my main problem is how to separate the data by splitting "|" then put the records in a user array. So when I do a login function I can loop through the array to match users.

My current code for reading is

```c
string User::readUser(){
    ifstream fin("user.txt");
    string line;
    while(getline(line,fin)){
        string name, password, address; int postal, phone;//put the records into a 2 dimention array
    }
    //return array
}
```

Comment: I suggest you take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/how-to-split-a-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/how-to-split-a-string/236803#236803).

In your case, the fields will be appended to the `vector<string>` in order, so you can access them directly from it. First position would correspond to the name, second to the password and so on.

Here's an example:

```
// The elements should be in this order: name, password, address, postal, phone
vector<string> v = split(line, '|');
string name = v[0], password = v[1], address = v[2];
```

As for your second question, you could create a structure or class that describes the user:

```
struct User {

    // Using type string for all fields for convenience.
    string name, password, address, postal, phone;

    User(string n, string pw, string a, string p, string ph): name(n),
                                                              password(pw),
                                                              address(a),
                                                              postal(p),
                                                              phone(ph) {}

};

vector<User> uv;

// ...

// Split string, create user instance and append it to the user list
vector<string> v = split(line, '|');
uv.push_back(User(v[0], v[1], v[2], v[3], v[4]));
```

To iterate over the `User` vector:

```
for (int i = 0; i < uv.size(); ++i) {
    if (uv[i].name == "John") {
        // Process John...
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, sorry, i am really dumb, i dont understand that code actually, do you mind to reconstruct for me.....

Comment: hi i have one more question. the vector ouptput is for a single record only, but in my question, i want to store all the users in a single array, so i can loop to match the user, what can i do in this case

Comment: Updated my answer, but I didn't test the code. Let me know if it works!

Comment: thanks, last question, how can i loop uv now? for example looping uv to check a user with name "john"

Answer (score 1):

Some time ago I wrote an answer with a [C++ `sscanf` replacement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5035256/c-boost-writing-a-more-powerful-sscanf-replacement/5043618#5043618). It fits perfectly for your case:

```
std::vector<boost::any> user_data;
sscanf(line, "%s|%s|%s|%i|%i", user_data);
```

Now constructing a `User` (a struct like in Matheus Moreira's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263404/read-write-data-then-seperate-data/5263605#5263605)) is very simple:

```
User(boost::any_cast<std::string>(user_data[0]), // name
     boost::any_cast<std::string>(user_data[1]), // password
     boost::any_cast<std::string>(user_data[2]), // address
     boost::any_cast<int>(user_data[3]),  // postal
     boost::any_cast<int>(user_data[4])); // phone
```

This requires [boost](http://www.boost.org/)'s [any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/doc/html/any.html) and [lexical_cast](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/conversion/lexical_cast.htm).

Comment: Nice solution! Just out of curiosity, is it possible to eliminate the `boost` dependency?

Comment: @Matheus Of course you could modify the sscanf replacement to only use `std::string`s, but than it practically would be your solution – so yes, the boost dependency is necessary … or you write your own `any` and `lexical_cast`.

Comment: since reading a file, why can we use sscanf instead of fstream??

Comment: @user594649 Of course you read the file with ifstream, I'm just talking of stuff inside the `while(getline())` loop. BTW typing "user594649" isn't that funny – maybe you can think of something better?

Answer (score 0):

The obvious solution would be to use boost::regex on each line: this
will do input format checking as well as separate out the fields.
Something like:

```
while ( getline( line, fin ) ) {
    static boost::regex const pattern(
        "\\([^|]+\\)\\|\\([^|]+\\)|\\([^|]+\\)|\\([^|]+\\)|\\([^|]+\\)" );
    boost::smatch match;
    if ( !regex_match( line, match, pattern ) ) {
        //  Error handling...
    } else {
        // match[1] is name, match[2] is password, etc.
    }
}
```

More complex matching patterns are possible, requiring e.g. postal and
phone to be numeric.  You could also easily modify it to allow leading
and trailing white space as well.